# Testing calling the right function dependent on the condition - sinon/mocha - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, testing, mocha.js, sinon

I would like to ask if can be tested calling the right function dependent on the condition with sinon or mocha. For example I have *class Knight* and I want to know if a *function (knightRun)* is called, when parameter 'data' is true.

```
export class Knight {

        createKnight(data,reducer) {
            if (data) {
              this.knightRun(reducer);
            } else if (!data) {
                this.knightFight(reducer);
            }
        }

        private knightFight(reducer) {
            // do something
        }

        private knightRun(reducer) {
            // do something
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spies to check whether a particular function has been called. [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.1.0/spies/) is a library which provides a way to spy on functions when writing unit tests for your JavaScript.

e.g.

```
describe('Knight class', () => {
  it('should call knightRun when data is false', () => {
    const knight = new Knight().createKnight(false, null)
    sinon.spy(knight, "knightRun")
    assert(knight.knightRun.calledOnce)
  })

  it('should call knightFight when data is true', () => {
    const knight = new Knight().createKnight(true, null)
    sinon.spy(knight, "knightFight")
    assert(knight.knightFight.calledOnce)
  })
})
```

As an aside, the `private` keyword is not valid JavaScript.